# is there a way to go through all the keys in two dictionarys and change all duplicate items so the dictionarys items are all different

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am a new programmer and am writing some code for a personnel assignment and I need to make sure two dictionarys with identical keys has no identical items. I need to search for the identical items and change them.

Im using python 3 and have tried messing with for loops but have not gotten anything to work but Im guessing that is because of my only basic understanding of them.

In the code below it may seem as though i can just check through each variable and change the variables individually but for the purpose of learning and whats actually in my full script id like to do it the way i described.

```
from random import choice

names = ['jacob', 'josh', 'alex', 'tyler']
weapons = ['swords', 'ax', 'rock', 'nothing']
armor = ['chest plate', 'none', 'vest', 'mask']

# I dont want to change values through these variables if possible
p1_name = choice(names)
p2_name = choice(names)

p1_weapon = choice(weapons)
p2_weapon = choice(weapons)

p1_armor = choice(armor)
p2_armor = choice(armor)

#here are the dictionarys  I want to change
p1 = {'name': p1_name, 'weapon': p1_weapon, 'armor': p1_armor}
p2 = {'name': p2_name, 'weapon': p2_weapon, 'armor': p2_armor}
```

I also know I can probably go through every key manually i.e.:

```
if p1['name'] == p2['name']:
```

but if its possible to do it through some sort of loop I'd prefer that because throughout my original code the dicts will change.

Comment: what do you mwan by *with identical keys has no identical items*? and change them how?

Comment: I think he means that no two people should have the same inventory in his game.

Comment: yeah that is still quite clear, but let's say we find a duplicate, what to do with it?

Comment: @Tomerikoo  I just want to change the items to a different string on the appropriate list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect your lists also in a dict and then assuming your dictionaries have similar keys (as your example suggests) you could use a loop like so:

```py
database = {'name': ['jacob', 'josh', 'alex', 'tyler'],
            'weapon': ['swords', 'ax', 'rock', 'nothing'],
            'armor': ['chest plate', 'none', 'vest', 'mask']}

for key in p1.keys():
    if p1[key] == p2[key]:
        p2[key] = choice(database[key])
```

---

To avoid that check at all, you could actually make sure from the start that no two similar items will be assigned by using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```py
from random import sample

names = ['jacob', 'josh', 'alex', 'tyler']
weapons = ['swords', 'ax', 'rock', 'nothing']
armor = ['chest plate', 'none', 'vest', 'mask']

p1_name, p2_name = sample(names, 2)

p1_weapon, p2_weapon = sample(weapons, 2)

p1_armor, p2_armor = sample(armor, 2)

p1 = {'name': p1_name, 'weapon': p1_weapon, 'armor': p1_armor}
p2 = {'name': p2_name, 'weapon': p2_weapon, 'armor': p2_armor}
```

Comment: I like the simple for loop above now how would i use that to change the p2 dict. say the names were the same and i wanted the p2 dict to use a different name from the names list

Comment: You would simply change it, but then you will face the problem of repeatedly checking if it might be the same again and again... This is why I would recommend the `sample` option as it takes out the need for a check altogether... If you still insist on a check, I have updated my answer

Comment: i accidentally deleted my comment when trying to edit it but it works fine it was an error on my end thank you for answering quickly and correctly

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the list of things you have, then let first person get 0th item of every list, second person 1st, and so on. As long as the list of inventory is unique, everyone will have a unique set of equipment:

```py
from random import choice, shuffle

names = ['jacob', 'josh', 'alex', 'tyler']
weapons = ['swords', 'ax', 'rock', 'nothing']
armor = ['chest plate', 'none', 'vest', 'mask']

shuffle(names)
shuffle(weapons)
shuffle(armor)
people = []
for i in range(2):
    people.append({
        'name': names[i],
        'weapon': weapons[i],
        'armor': armor[i]
    })
print(people)

# unpack the list to get two separate persons
p1, p2 = people
print(p1)
print(p2)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'tyler', 'weapon': 'nothing', 'armor': 'chest plate'}, {'name': 'josh', 'weapon': 'rock', 'armor': 'mask'}]
{'name': 'tyler', 'weapon': 'nothing', 'armor': 'chest plate'}
{'name': 'josh', 'weapon': 'rock', 'armor': 'mask'}
```

Comment: this is great and almost exactly what I needed but is it possible to create them as separate dicts outside of a list